# How to find user going off track from path on google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am drawing path on google map between two locations.
Now I want to find if the user deviates from the path that is already being drawn
Is there any way that I can use?[image]

The arrow in the image shows deviated path.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the PolyUtil.isLocationOnEdge() method, with this you can determine whether or not the current position is "on track" or not.

More information:

http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html

Answer (score 0):

Use PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(...) from [Google Maps Android API utility library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/).